# How to use var as counter as cumulative value

Tags: mysql

In my query I want to use an a counter of minutes.

```
SET @totalcount=SEC_TO_TIME(0);

select
@totalcount := @totalcount + getTimePeriodBetweenTwoStops(r1.time1, r1.time2)
-- , getTimePeriodBetweenTwoStops(r1.time1, r1.time2)
,r1.*
from route r1
```

The function getTimePeriodBetweenTwoStops really returns me the TIME between two points.
But I don't know why I can't increase counter (@totalcount) by returned value.
@totalcount gets NULL everytime :'(

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `addtime()`?

```
SET @totalcount=SEC_TO_TIME(0);

select
@totalcount := addtime(@totalcount, getTimePeriodBetweenTwoStops(r1.time1, r1.time2))
-- , getTimePeriodBetweenTwoStops(r1.time1, r1.time2)
,r1.*
from route r1
```

Comment: Doesn't help. NULL again.